# How to get Java to accept some user input and pass the information to some methods?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a main method in Java that accepts some user input and passes it to some methods.

My Code so far:

```
//this method prints a menu to the console
public static void menu(){
    System.out.println("Select one of the following:\n");
    System.out.println("Enter Observatory Data[1]");
    System.out.println("Enter Earthquake Data[2]");
    System.out.println("Get Largest Ever Earthquake[3]");
    System.out.println("Get All Earthquakes Greater Than X[4]");
    System.out.println("Exit[5]");

}


public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner reader= new Scanner(System.in);
    menu(); //print the menu to screen
    String input1=reader.next(); //user should select 1,2,3,4 or 5
    boolean cheese=false; //keep the program running
    while (cheese=false){
        if (input1.matches("[a-zA-Z67890]*")){ //if anything but 1,2,3,4,or 5 is entered return this string and reprint the menu
            //int inputNum1=Integer.parseInt(input1);
            System.out.println("no work!");
            menu();
            String input2=reader.next();
        }else if(input1.matches("1")){ //if user types 1 accept some information and pass it to the Observatory method
            System.out.println("What is the Observatory name?");
            String observatoryName = reader.next();
            System.out.println("What country is the observatory in?");
            String country = reader.next();
            System.out.println("What year did the observatory open??");
            String year = reader.next();
            System.out.println("Observatory added. Waht next?");
            System.out.println("What area does the observatory cover?");
            String area = reader.next();
            Observatory newObservatory = new Observatory(observatoryName,country,Integer.parseInt(year),Double.parseDouble(area));
```

There are also some other options but only pasting one should suffice here. The current code runs, prints a menu and accepts some user input but as soon as it does the program terminates, despite the `boolean cheese` remaining `false`. Does anybody have a suggestion as to how I can get Java to run until option 5 is typed and to retrieve some information when 1 is selected?

Comment: while (cheese=false) should be while (cheese==false)

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but it might be easier to use a switch statement instead of using a bunch of "if/else", I feel like the default case could be very useful.

Comment: Actually, it should be `while (!cheese)`

Comment: As stated, the problem is probably around the (cheese=false) but it's hard to know if the rest is correct without seeing where you are setting cheese.

Comment: Ah of course. Me and my Matlab ways holding me back. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your while loop condition, you are setting cheese to false instead of comparing cheese with false. Change it to

```
while (cheese == false) {
```

or

```
while(!cheese) {
```

You can also wait for more user input after you last actual input. So after you last line, add this:

```
reader.next();
```

so that the program waits for further user input before exiting. If I understand your program correctly, you can do this, remove the while loop, and achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Without seeing more of their code, I can't vote that you've answered the question.

Comment: Ah of course. Me and my Matlab ways holding me back. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your while condition is incorrect...
It should be:

```
boolean cheese = true;
while (cheese) 
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

or if you really want to have your cheese boolean to be false, just do this:

```
boolean cheese = false;
while (!cheese) 
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```